# Visual basic compiler error

Tags: excel, vba

I received an error in the below coding as Object Required in the marked line. Please help me out. The Temp file means a template and the details are derived from the Combo code which are the data which needs to be filled in the template and which sends emails based on the code below.

```
Sub Emails()
    Dim R_No As Integer

    Templ.Select
    Templ.Range("C11") = ""
    Templ.Range("D11") = ""
    Templ.Range("E11") = ""
    Temp1.Range("F11") = "" <-------- Error
    Temp1.Range("G11") = ""
    Templ.Range("C14") = ""
    Templ.Range("D14") = ""
    Templ.Range("E14") = ""
    Temp1.Range("F14") = ""
    Temp1.Range("G14") = ""
    Rows("10:11").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("13:14").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    R_No = 2
    Do Until Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = ""
        If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Order" Then
            Combo.Cells(R_No, 13) = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
        Else
            Combo.Cells(R_No, 13) = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "  &  " & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
        End If

        If Combo.Cells(R_No, 7) = Combo.Cells(R_No + 1, 7) Then
            If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = Combo.Cells(R_No + 1, 1) Then
                If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Order" Then
                    Rows("10:11").Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If Templ.Range("C11") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Templ.Range("C11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Templ.Range("D11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Templ.Range("E11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F11") = Templ.Range("F11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G11") = Templ.Range("G11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    End If
                End If
                If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Receipt" Then
                    Rows("13:14").Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If Templ.Range("C14") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Templ.Range("C14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Templ.Range("D14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Templ.Range("E14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F14") = Templ.Range("F14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G14") = Templ.Range("G14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Order" Then
                    Rows("10:11").Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If Templ.Range("C11") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Templ.Range("C11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Templ.Range("D11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Templ.Range("E11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F11") = Templ.Range("F11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G11") = Templ.Range("G11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    End If
                End If
                If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Receipt" Then
                    Rows("13:14").Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    If Templ.Range("C14") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Templ.Range("C14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Templ.Range("D14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Templ.Range("E14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F14") = Templ.Range("F14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G14") = Templ.Range("G14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Order" Then
                Rows("10:11").Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                If Templ.Range("C11") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C11") = Templ.Range("C11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
                        Templ.Range("D11") = Templ.Range("D11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E11") = Templ.Range("E11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F11") = Templ.Range("F11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G11") = Templ.Range("G11") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                End If
            End If
            If Combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = "Receipt" Then
                Rows("13:14").Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                If Templ.Range("C14") = "" Then
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Temp1.Range("F14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Temp1.Range("G14") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                    Else
                        Templ.Range("C14") = Templ.Range("C14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & "-" & Combo.Cells(R_No, 4)
                        Templ.Range("D14") = Templ.Range("D14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
                        Templ.Range("E14") = Templ.Range("E14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
                        Templ.Range("F14") = Templ.Range("F14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
                        Templ.Range("G14") = Templ.Range("G14") & Templ.Range("I2") & Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
                End If
            End If
            Templ.Range("C6") = "Dear " & Left(Combo.Cells(R_No, 7), InStr(1, Combo.Cells(R_No, 7), " ") - 1) & ","
            Templ.Range("A1:H48").Select
            ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
            ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templete").MailEnvelope
               .Item.Subject = "Reminder- Order(s) / Receipt(s) Pending Your Urgent Approval"
               .Item.To = Combo.Cells(R_No, 8)
               .Item.cc = " "
               If Combo.Cells(R_No, 10) <> "" Then
                    .Item.cc = Combo.Cells(R_No, 12)
               Else
               End If
               .Item.Send

               Templ.Range("C11") = ""
               Templ.Range("D11") = ""
               Templ.Range("E11") = ""
               Templ.Range("F11") = ""
               Templ.Range("G11") = ""
               Templ.Range("C14") = ""
               Templ.Range("D14") = ""
               Templ.Range("E14") = ""
               Templ.Range("F14") = ""
               Templ.Range("G14") = ""

               Rows("10:11").Select
               Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
               Rows("13:14").Select
               Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End With
        End If
        R_No = R_No + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

The F11 statement has temp1 {ONE} instead of TEMPL.  So does G11

```
Templ.Range("E11") = ""
Temp1.Range("F11") = ""
```

Comment: Along with G11, F14, and G14.

Answer (score 0):

As cardmagik pointed out, you need to replace `Temp1` (with a number one at the end) with `Templ`(with the letter L at the end).

In addition, just a few improvement suggestions to your code:

- Always use `Option Explicit` at the start of your module - this way, you will be told, if you misspelled a variable like in this example!
- To empty the cells in the beginning, simply write `Temp.Range("C11:G11,C14:G14").Value = ""` instead of spelling out every cell
- Almost all the time you do `X.Select` and then `Selection.DoSomething`, you can replace this with `X.DoSomething` - easier to read, less errorprone and faster to execute
- Combining the above two point, you can simplify

  ```
  Rows("10:11").Select
  Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Rows("13:14").Select
  Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ```

  to `Rows("10:11,13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True`
- You have a lot of repetitive code. For instance,

  ```
  Templ.Range("C11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 2)
  Templ.Range("D11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 3)
  Templ.Range("E11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 5)
  Temp1.Range("F11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 6)
  Temp1.Range("G11") = Combo.Cells(R_No, 9)
  ```

  is called 3 times - and if you consider the very similar code for row 14, even 6x! Instead, create a `Sub` with two parameters - and call it 6x! This sub could look like this:

  ```
  Private Sub FillDefault(rowTarget As Long, rowSource as Long)
  Templ.Range("C" & rowTarget) = Combo.Cells(rowSource, 2)
  Templ.Range("D" & rowTarget) = Combo.Cells(rowSource, 3)
  Templ.Range("E" & rowTarget) = Combo.Cells(rowSource, 5)
  Templ.Range("F" & rowTarget) = Combo.Cells(rowSource, 6)
  Templ.Range("G" & rowTarget) = Combo.Cells(rowSource, 9)
  End Sub
  ```

  and then call it with `FillDefault 11, R_No` and `FillDefault 14, R_No`
- Your nested `IF...THEN...ELSE...` statements are completely pointless in this version - **every branch is doing the same!!!** - only in one branch, you send the email, in addition to all other steps! So it's much better, to do the other steps before - and then just send the email
- Instead of `IF cond1 Then x = 1 Else x = 2` you can use `x = Iif(cond1, 1, 2)` - this often results in shorted code, esp. if x is a longer term
- Is your sheet really called `Templete`or rather `Template`?
- When referring to row numbers, better use Long instead of Integer - Integers will only work till 32,768

All in all, I reworked your code - and reduced it from a whopping 169 rows to 60 rows (though this could be reduced further, but then at the sake of readability):

```
Sub Emails()
    Dim R_No As Long

    ClearSheet

    R_No = 2
    Do Until combo.Cells(R_No, 1) = ""

        combo.Cells(R_No, 13) = combo.Cells(R_No, 2) & _
            IIf(combo.Cells(R_No, 1) <> "Order", "  &  " & combo.Cells(R_No, 4), "")

        Select Case combo.Cells(R_No, 1)
            Case "Order":
                Rows("10:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Fill rowTarget:=11, rowSource:=R_No, blnAdd:=(Templ.Range("C11") = "")
            Case "Receipt":
                Rows("13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Fill rowTarget:=14, rowSource:=R_No, blnAdd:=(Templ.Range("C14") = "")
        End Select

        If combo.Cells(R_No, 7) <> combo.Cells(R_No + 1, 7) Then
            SendMail R_No
            ClearSheet
        End If
        R_No = R_No + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub ClearSheet()
    Templ.Range("C11:G11,C14:G14").Value = ""
    Rows("10:11,13:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub

Private Sub Fill(rowTarget As Long, rowSource As Long, _
    Optional blnAdd As Boolean = False)
    Dim a As Variant, i As Integer
    a = Array(2, 3, 5, 6, 9)
    For i = 0 To 4
        Templ.Cells(rowTarget, i + 3) = _
            IIf(blnAdd, Templ.Cells(rowTarget, i + 3) & Templ.Range("I2"), "") & _
            combo.Cells(rowSource, a(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SendMail(R_No As Long)
    Templ.Range("C6") = "Dear " & Left(combo.Cells(R_No, 7), _
        InStr(1, combo.Cells(R_No, 7), " ") - 1) & ","
    Templ.Range("A1:H48").Select
    ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templete").MailEnvelope.Item
       .Subject = "Reminder- Order(s) / Receipt(s) Pending Your Urgent Approval"
       .To = combo.Cells(R_No, 8)
       .cc = " "
       If combo.Cells(R_No, 10) <> "" Then
            .cc = combo.Cells(R_No, 12)
       End If
       .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH!